# Search and Replace with variable using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, search, replace

i want to search and replace an entire string that has changing text inside it

**Example:**

```
<option value="AU">Australia</option>
<option value="AT">Austria</option>
<option value="AZ">Azerbaijan</option>
<option value="BS">Bahamas</option>
<option value="BH">Bahrain</option>
<option value="BD">Bangladesh</option>
```

**To:**

```
Australia
Austria
Azerbaijan
Bahamas
Bahrain
Bangladesh
```

The problem is of course that changing value... meaning value="$var"...
How can search and replace all occurrences using jquery / javascript.

Would appreciate your help.

Comment: I din't get what do you mean by changing value ?

Comment: You want to retrieve the text from the `<option>` elements? And put them where?

Comment: The chaning value in this case is 1st option: AU, 2nd option: AT and so on.its easy for to use the string.replace for xxx some string xxx. the problam (for me) start when i try to replace xx12x some string xxx, xx23 some string xxx, etc (hope this clears it) ;) - sometimes its hard to explaing these things from a distance.

Comment: p.s i did write this under the example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this approach:

```
$('option').each(function() {
   var text = $(this).text();
   $(this).after(text);
   $(this).remove();
});
```

I can't test it right now but it should do the job.
Let me know how it goes.

OR

You can try this way:

```
$('option').html(function(index, html)
    return html.replace(/<option[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/option>/g, "$1");
});
```

Good luck!

Comment: @SagiveSEO: Of course, this leaves you with text directly inside whatever contained the `option` elements, which was presumabl a `select`, `datalist`, or `optgroup`, none of which is meant to have straight text in it I don't think (not entirely sure about how `datalist` is supposed to handle that)... :-)

Comment: thats exactly what i needed - i was actully looked for something i could turn into a flexible tool since i need this feature a lot and create a localized page i can use to change string which have a varible - this was easy to customize to that end. thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading your question right, you're dealing with a *string*, not with elements, so you can use `String#replace`:

```
theString = theString.replace(/<option[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/option>/g, "$1");
```

`replace` looks for special sequences in the replacement string, and fills them in from information on the matched occurrence. In this case, I'm using a capture group to capture the bit between `<option...>` and `</option>`, then using `$1` to replace the overall match with the content of the first capture group.

Complete example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/diwefu/1/) *(I've added `<br>` between them just for output purposes):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Example</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>
  (function() {
    "use strict";

    var theString =
        '<option value="AU">Australia</option><br>' +
        '<option value="AT">Austria</option>' +
        '<br><option value="AZ">Azerbaijan</option>' +
        '<br><option value="BS">Bahamas</option>' +
        '<br><option value="BH">Bahrain</option>' +
        '<br><option value="BD">Bangladesh</option>';

    theString = theString.replace(/<option[^>]*>([^<]+)<\/option>/g, "$1");
    display(theString);

    function display(msg) {
      var p = document.createElement('p');
      p.innerHTML = String(msg);
      document.body.appendChild(p);
    }
  })();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i love this, much more flexible than other solutions offered here. Testing... brb.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$('select').children().each(function(i,el){
    $(el).val($(el).text());   
});
```

Of course, this assumes that's the only select element on the page. If not, you'll either have to choose the right one, hopefully using it's id or, if not maybe using `eq()`.